# Value of remainder

Tags: python, modulus

I am looking for a way to extract the fractional part of a number in python. I am fairly new to Python and have dabbled in MatLab in college, nothing serious. I understand that the % operator reports the quantity of number placements in the fractional part. I need to be able to get the actual value of the fractional part as well as the actual value of the whole number but separate them to conduct the following equation:

Problem:
Converting a time calculation from say 1.5minutes to 1.30 (1minute and .30seconds)

Eq. (((1.5-1)*60)/100)+1

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the remainder of a integer number"? Integers don't have remainders. The concept makes no sense.

Comment: Or actually I really just need to determine what the actual value of the whole number is. I don't know what operator could do that.

Comment: Lol i apologize if you can't understand what I trying to explain. Like I stated before, new to this. So, in other words say you have the value 1.5. How do i extract the .5?

Comment: This is called "fractional part" in English.

Comment: whats it called in python language?

Comment: fraction_part = 1.5 - int(1.5)?

Comment: To get the remainder, you need "modulo" %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you extract the fractional part of a floating point number like this:

```
x = 1.5
x -= int(x)
```

However, as you mentioned minutes and seconds, I believe that what you really need is:

```
minutes = int(x)
seconds = (x-minutes)*60
```

Comment: awesome. thanks for the help. first time asking a question. very good feedback